# Identification of a plant

Tags: wildflowers

Could anyone identify this plant for me please.  It was spotted in a wooded gill, ancient woodland, amongst bluebells and wild garlic.  Not in a boggy situation.
[image]

Comment: I wonder who ate the bottom part of the flower?

Comment: In which country did you find it?

Comment: Found in the north east of england

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a flower from the Arum family. The spadix (floral spike) is visible in the hole. The top part of the flower is missing.

In England Arum maculatum will be the most common species. The [german wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gefleckter_Aronstab) has some good pictures of the spadix.